# Location of "Only" in a Sentence

Tags: grammar, only

If one were to say that the day of the week on which it rained was Tuesday and no other day, one would say "It rained only on Tuesday".

One could argue that "It only rained on Tuesday" would also be acceptable. However it could be argued that "It only rained on Tuesday" implies that the only thing it did on Tuesday was rain. While the first way is definitely clearer, could it be argued that the second way is also correct, albeit open to misinterpretation?

Comment: What's the question that prompted "It rained only on Tuesday" or "It only rained on Tuesday" as an answer?

Comment: @killingTime Not sure it matters. Let's say the question was "When did it rain?" And you answered "It only rained on Tuesday." The person will probably be able to figure out what you mean but is your response proper? Like if you responded "Tuesday are the only day it rained" the person will be able to figure out what you mean but that doesn't make it right.